# Does anyone know why my form validation is not working in my upload component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, react-hooks

I am trying to allow a user to submit an image and a title for that image that gets sent to my backend API. I want a user to not be able to submit to that API if the title input box is empty. So I figured I need to implement a form validation for this. But for some reason, it is not working. Can someone help me figure out what I need to do to get it working so that the error displays when the title input is empty? I have a sandbox also if that helps. https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-frog-ui4413?file=/src/App.js

Upload.jsx:

```html
import '../../components/pages/styles/Uploads.css';
import {Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage} from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {} from 'react-router-dom';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import {clearMessage} from '../../slices/messages';
import authHeader from '../../services/auth-header';
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/posts';

function Uploads() {
    const {user: currentUser} = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
    const [file, setFile] = useState();
    const [title, setTitle] = useState();
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [content, setContent] = useState('');
    const [preview, setPreview] = useState(null);
    const initialValues = {
        title: '',
    };
    const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(initialValues);
    const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {}, []);

    const validate = (values) => {
        const errors = {};
        if (!values.title) {
            errors.title = 'Title of Post is required!';
        }
        return errors;
    };

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const {name, value} = e.target;
        setFormValues({...formValues, [name]: value});
    };

    const handlePost = (formValue) => {};

    const onAddImage = (file) => {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(preview);
        if (!file) return;
        setPreview(window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
    };
    const postUserImage = async (event) => {
        //This is the code that will get passed to my backend. I need the image and title to be added here somehow.
        event.preventDefault();

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        formData.append('title', formValues.title);

        const result = await axios.post('/post/upload', formData, {
            headers: {...authHeader(), 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
        });
        console.log(result.data);
        setFormErrors(validate(formValues));
    };

    return (
        <div className='page'>
            <div className='upload-card'>
                <div id='preview'>
                    <img
                        src={preview || require('../../assets/user-solid.jpeg')}
                        id='image'
                        alt='Thumbnail'
                        className='user-post'
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='upload-container'>
                <div className='post-form-container'>
                    <p id='upload-form-label'>Hello, feel free to post an image!</p>
                    <form
                        // onSubmit={'return Validate(this);'}

                        onSubmit={postUserImage}
                        className='upload-form'
                    >
                        <div className='panel'>
                            <div className='button_outer'>
                                <div className='btn_upload'>
                                    <input
                                        filename={file}
                                        onChange={(e) => onAddImage(e.target.files[0])}
                                        type='file'
                                        accept='.jpeg,.svg,.gif,.png'
                                        id='image-selection-btn'
                                    ></input>
                                    Choose your Art
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input
                            type='text'
                            className='form-control'
                            placeholder='Enter Title'
                            id='cred-input'
                            value={formValues.title}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            initialValues={initialValues}
                        />

                        <button type='submit' id='post-upload-btn'>
                            Upload Image
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Uploads;
```

Comment: you need useEffect to check for formErrors there... or Idealy in the handleSubmit check the formErrors.

Comment: am I not doing that with setFormErrors(validate(formValues)); in my postUserImage method? any help would be appreciated, thank you so much